# How to fill tableRow with editText in all row

Tags: android, android-layout, tablerow

I have table layout with some rows. One row is for description next one is for editText to get some values. How can i force this EditText to fill table row?
I thought i did it with android:layout_weight="1" but when i will type something into that editText it will grow to the side and crush my layout. Even when i´m not reaching the max lenght of word i can put into editText.

Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout">


<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"

    android:id="@+id/table">


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/name">

        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Název"
            android:padding="3dip"
            />

    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/nameEdit">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tariffName"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext"/>

    </TableRow>
```

Edit: screen added

Before input

[image: Before input]

After input

[image: After input]

Answer (score 0):

Well, solved by myself. I used android:layout_span="3" insted of android:layout_weight="1".